# Find the direction of a path using Google Direction API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-directions-api

I am using Google Places API and direction API to mark the route between 2 places. I get a polyline for this route. Now I have another polyline which lies on this route.

Eg:  Point A to point B -> initial polyline
Point C to point D -> second polyline which lies on the A->B polyline.

Using isLocationOnEdge() method, I was able to find out if the C->D polyline lies on the A->B polyline or not.

Problem is I want to find out if the path C->D is in the direction of A->B or reverse. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry), you have a `computeHeading` method available. Please see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical).

You could therefore compute the heading between points A and B and compare it with the heading of points C to D.

```
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path.getAt(0), path.getAt(1));
```

Where `path` is your first polyline. Then do the same for the second one and compare the results.

Hope this helps.